# Typescript: How to monkey patch `history.pushState` without using ts-ignore?

Tags: typescript, browser-history, html5-history

I am trying to implement `history` API patching the way the [`wouter`](https://github.com/molefrog/wouter/blob/master/use-location.js) routing library does it, but in Typescript instead of Javascript.

The `wouter` library uses code like this:

```
["pushState", "replaceState"].map(type => {
  const original = history[type];

  history[type] = function() {
    const result = original.apply(this, arguments);
    const event = new Event(type);
    event.arguments = arguments;

    dispatchEvent(event);
    return result;
  };
});
```

Which I have adapted into Typescript:

```
type WindowHistoryFn =
  (data: any, title: string, url?: (string | null)) => void;

function patchHistoryPushState(){
  const original: WindowHistoryFn = window.history.pushState;

  window.history.pushState = function(data: any, title: string, url?: (string | null)): void{
    const result = original.apply(this, [data, title, url]);
    const event = new Event("pushState");
    // @ts-ignore
    event.arguments = arguments;

    dispatchEvent(event);
    return result;
  };
}
```

This seems to work, but I don't understand the line `event.arguments = arguments`.

The `Event` type doesn't have an `arguments` field.  Is there a different type of `Event` I should be instantiating?  How can I re-write the above Typescript function to not use `ts-ignore`?

Comment: What is the subscriber to the pushState event?

Comment: Since JavaScript is duck typed you can add whatever you want. But in TypeScript world you'll need to create your own interface that is extended from `Event` or you can use `CustomEvent`, but instead of arguments you'd have to populate `detail`

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is duck typed you can add whatever you want. But in TypeScript world you'll need to create your own interface that is extended from `Event` or you can use `CustomEvent`. If you use `CustomEvent` then you need to populate `detail`  instead of `arguments`.

You can refer to `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event`